# Correctly install a depenency from composer

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, laravel-7

I have installed the last version of laravel (7).
Now I need a certain package:( mercadopago/dx-php )

And throws the following conflict:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for mercadopago/dx-php ^2.0 -> satisfiable by mercadopago/dx-php[2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/inflector 2.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/inflector 2.0.3

- mercadopago/dx-php 2.0.0 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].

 - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.2, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.3, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.2.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.3.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.3.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.0.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.1.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0, 2.0.3].
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector (locked at 2.0.3) -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[2.0.3].
```

I tried:

```
composer depends doctrine/inflector
```

And throws: `laravel/framework  v7.15.0  requires  doctrine/inflector (^1.4|^2.0)`

If I understood correctly, everything will work fine if I remove doctrine/inflector[2.0.3], and install, for example, doctrine/inflector[1.4.3].

composer.lock has the following:

```
"name": "doctrine/inflector",
            "version": "2.0.3",
            "source": {... etc
```

What is the correct way of installing doctrine/inflector version 1.4.3, having already installed 2.0.3?

Comment: maybe just: `composer require doctrine/inflector:^1.4`

Comment: Yeah!, seems that, it did the trick, I dont know If anything would break though...

Answer (score 4):

Seems everything works fine just by doing

```
composer require doctrine/inflector:1.4.0
```

It throws the following warning when doing composer diagnose though:

require.doctrine/inflector : exact version constraints (1.4.3) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your file **composer.lock**, remove your folder **vendor** and run **composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:2.2.1"**

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `doctrine/inflector:1.4.0` brought me some problems, such as the reflection of name of tables in the database for models.

The most viable solution, it seems to me, is to install `mecadopago/dx-php` in another directory and include this new autoload in your application's payment service.

Comment: That's is incorrect way of using composer. Bad practice.

Comment: I agree. But unfortunately I was not able to get around the conflicts.